# while (!feof($handle)) -- Error code to warning information

Tags: php

http://www.example.com/pageView?test=111&test2=999  -> data loading and working..

```
189 <?php
190 $handle = @fopen("http://www.example.com". htmlspecialchars($_GET["test"]) ."/".     htmlspecialchars($_GET["test2"]) .".txt", "r");
191    while (!feof($handle))
192 {
193 $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
194
195 if (strlen(trim($buffer)) > 0){
196
197 list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j)=explode(",",$buffer);
198
199 $items[] = array('col1' => $a,'col2' => $b,'col3' => $c,'col4' => $d,'col5' => $e,'col6' => $f,'col7' => $g,'col8' => $h,'col9' => $i,'col10' => $j);

200 }
201 }
202 ?>
```

http://www.example.com/pageView?test&test2=   -> Not loading.. this is normal but this error is in the page..

```
Warning: feof(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/---/public_html/---/---.php on line 191

Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/---/public_html/---/---.php on line 193
```

How to show the warning letter instead of an error page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - feof error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875971/php-feof-error)

Comment: remove error supression from fopen call for a clue as to what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of `fopen`. If there was error during reading you'll get $handle equal to false, but you need to pass "stream resource" to `eof`

```
if($handle === false) {
    print 'Err found';
}
else {
   while(!eof($handle)) ...
}
```

Comment: @TheSaracoglu accepted the answer by clicking the "correct " (accepted) sign.